# Multiple tsconfig on a Visual Studio 2015 Project [typescript 1.8]

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8

I have a MVC 5 project where I use typescript.
Now I have to implements new features I it open other typescript implementation way.
I'm trying to use multiple `tsconfig.json` file new feature of typescript 1.8, I have two folders: `typescriptE21` and `typescript`, and a `tsconfig.json` file on each folder.

The first:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "removeComments": false,
        "sourceMap": false,
        "target": "es5",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "module": "amd",
        "declaration": false,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "inlineSourceMap": true,
        "inlineSources": true
    },
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "typescript"
    ]
}
```

and the second:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "removeComments": false,
        "sourceMap": false,
        "target": "es5",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "module": "system",
        "declaration": false,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "inlineSourceMap": true,
        "inlineSources": true
    },
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "typescript21",
        "scripts"
    ]
}
```

When I open the project properties on Typescript section says "One or more tsconfig.json files detected. Project properties are disabled." that's correct but when I run the application I get this error:

`Build: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning`

On this file:

```
import {Component} from "ngts/ngts";

@Component({
    template: `<div md-scroll-y flex class="md-padding" id="contenido">Contenido</div>`
})
export class EmAplicacion {

}
```

In both `tsconfig.json` files I have activated the decorators but seems that typescript doesn't get the compiler options from there ...

In addition, when I don't use decorators, It compiles but I can see the result files and they are emited using AMD module system when I have put "system" in the second config file ...

What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real problem is that `tsconfig.json` files are included on prject as:

```
<None Include="typescript\tsconfig.json" />
```

I have change it by;

```
<Content Include="typescript\tsconfig.json" />
```

And all it's ok

Comment: Where do you do this?
What file?

Comment: I do it on .csproj file.

Answer (score 0):

This will also help:

1. Open Solution Explorer
2. Right click on the tsconfig.json file and choose 'Exclude From Project'.
3. You might see the tsconfig.json disappear from the Solution Explorer. In that case choose 'Show All Files' option from the top
   of the Solution Explorer toolbar.
4. Right click on the tsconfig.json and choose 'Include In Project'.